# How to deploy on JBoss exploded web application from Eclipse Galileo?

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, galileo

Is it possible to deploy on JBoss exploded web application(not archived war file) from Eclipse Galileo?

Answer (score 1):

JBoss Tools supports exploded deployment with both "native" Web Tools(WTP) style projects (i.e. those projects created by the Dynamic Web Project based wizards) and via the generic Project Archives plugins.

If you already got a WTP style project then you simply just need to install jboss tools and create a server from the "JBoss Community" or "JBoss Enterprise Platform" category (The "JBoss" one is the WTP generic server which is very incomplete) and deploy your project to the server and it will by default be deployed exploded.

If you want to deploy in zipped form there is an option for this in the server editor (double click on the server in the server view and look in the deployment section)

Answer (score 0):

We are using MyEclipse plugin for eclipse which has this specific capability, but it's a commercial plugin.
If you deploy your application only on JBoss, then you have the JBoss tools plugin for eclipse. According to their documentation they also support this mode and this plugin is free, but I have never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I used it but, according to [this post](http://relation.to/Bloggers/FastAndIncrementalPackagingInJBossTools), it should be possible using [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) (previously known as JBoss IDE, before the merge with Exadel). Quoting the blog post:

> One of my favorite feature in JBoss Tools is the "Project Archives" which provides automatic and incremental archiving of arbitrary directories into a zipped archive (jar,zip,war,etc) or into an exploded directory. Usable for any development that wants hot and/or exploded deployment.